# Cross-browser audio dysfunction with jQuery

Tags: jquery, web-services

I'm having a somewhat perplexing issue. I'm using jQuery to play a sound on a mouse over section of a page. When testing the script locally it works fine on all of the browsers I'm testing on (Firefox, Chrome and Safari), but when the script is uploaded to the server the sound is only played within Chrome.

What could be causing this problem?

I re-uploaded all of the files and still have the same issue.

The code chunk I'm using is below in case that it helps any. Thanks for any suggestions!

```
$("myElement").mouseenter(function playSound() {
$("#soundSpan").add("<audio autoplay='autoplay' preload='auto'> 
<source src='myAudio.mp3'/></audio>");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding the type attribute to your tag, also, I removed the name of the function inside of the callback, it will work without it

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp

```
$("myElement").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#soundSpan").add('<audio autoplay="autoplay" preload="auto"><source src="myAudio.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/></audio>');
});
```

Comment: No luck with adding the type attribute.

Comment: What is the relative path of the file that this script is in, and what is the relative path that the audio file is in?

Like is it /my-folder/index.html and the audio is at /myAudio.mp3?

Comment: The two are in separate folders, but the links shouldn't be an issue because the script works in Chrome, just not the other two. It's worth mentioning that I do indeed have an .ogg file for Firefox, which works fine locally.